# User interface crashes after Sentry throws an error

Tags: angular, angular-routing, sentry, angular-errorhandler

I'm using **Angular 7** and `ngx-admin` for a project. Also I'm using **Sentry** to log errors in a server. I have three level routes and the error occurs in the third level. When Sentry throws error the UI crashes. The problem is my routing or sentry?

Comment: please share some code which you have tried and where you are facing the issue.

Comment: there is no specific error for this I get. every error in the project happens then UI crashes. I used sentry configuration in my app.module

Comment: Is this sentry.io you are talking about or your self-hosted sentry instance?